# How to realize method TryAdd(T item, int millisecondsTimeout)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have wrote a thread safe list. But I need one more method. Specifically, I need a method with the second parameter -1 to thread waited as long as necessary, and the element just got in a collection. There are some code:

```
public sealed class ThreadSafeList<T>: IEnumerable
{
    private readonly List<T> _mList = new List<T>();
    private readonly object _mLock = new object();

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        lock (_mLock)
        {
            _mList.Add(value);
        }
    }
    public bool TryRemove(T value)
    {
        lock (_mLock)
        {
            return _mList.Remove(value);
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>) _mList).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the appropriate language tag next time. I assume this is C# code and added the tag for you.

Comment: You can start by typing `public void TryAdd(T item, int milliSecondsTimeout)`. With what part specifically are you having trouble? This list also isn't thread-safe, as you can sill add and remove items while enumerating.

Comment: Your threadsafe list isn't much useful. Assume you've modified the list while iterating over it. You'll end up with `InvalidOperationException` which also means it isn't thread safe.

Comment: The actual correct answer is: use one of the [Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collections.

Comment: There is no thread safe list in C#. We have blocking collection, but we can't take an item with index.
"Assume you've modified the list while iterating over it."
Thanks for that. I had not thought about it. So, I can lock an object while iterating over it, can't I?

Comment: @user3818229 I've updated my answer with a way to make your iterator thread-safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want the lock to timeout - use [`Monitor.TryEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then.

```
public bool TryAdd(T item, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    if(Monitor.TryEnter(_mLock, millisecondsTimeout))
    {
        try
        {
            //logic
            return true;
        }
        finally 
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_mLock)
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Update** Bonus question

If you want to make your iterator thread-safe, then you have to take a snapshot of it and return an iterator of that snapshot. This is what some of the built-in concurrent collections do. Here's an example implementation:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    lock(_mLock)
    {
        //ToList creates a snapshot of the list at this point in time
        return _mList.ToList().GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you may want to change your `void` returning type to a `bool` that indicates success or failure. Otherwise the caller won't be able to know.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Good point, that's part of the `TryXXX` pattern. Fixed my answer

Comment: Could you explain what is the difference between "return _mList.ToList().GetEnumerator()" and "return ((IEnumerable<T>) _mList).GetEnumerator()"? Why do we need to take a snapshot?

Comment: @user3818229 Your initial implementation synchronizes access to `_mList.GetEnumerator()` - **but**, once the enumerator has been created and returned, you're not synchronizing access to `enumerator.MoveNext()`. The enumerator will then be able to read the list, without any locks being taken. If some other thread changes the list *while* you're iterating over it, the iterator will become invalid.

Comment: @user3818229 Whereas if you create a snapshot of the list and return an enumerator for the snapshot, then there's no race condition. The snapshot itself **cannot** be modified, so the iterator will never become invalid.